# JSP data display auto update

Tags: jsp

Currently I am doing a guest book page. Which allow user to comment on certain items. Let say userA post a comment. How to do so that the new post will auto display on the page on userB browser? I am able to display the post on userA browser but how to do so that userB browser will also auto update to display the new post?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for reverse AJAX (a.k.a. [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)).

**Update:**

After you learn the basics, I would recommend you [Atmosphere](http://atmosphere.java.net/) for delivering the actual implementation. Also, if you can choose your container, I would go with [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) or [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/).

Comment: Google Mojo: http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-atmospheres-jquery-plug.
Comet is not something that you can learn from a stackoverflow post. Take your time to study and learn the techniques involved and when you have a more specific question feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you're coding some kind of instant messenger, where there should be a very small delay between the post and its appearance in userB's page, then look at Comet, as suggested by Anthony.

Else, the most simple way to achieve this is to have the page on userB regularly (every 2, 3, 5, 10 minutes: you decide what's acceptable) poll the server for new messages using an AJAX request. Make sure not to consume your whole bandwidth by doing this, though.

Comment: Yeah. An AJAX request or even something more old school like [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). But then again, take @JB advice, this can potentially consume a lot of bandwidth.

Comment: How about if is a auction site? how to reflect the data?

Comment: It depends on the bandwidth you (and the users) have, the numer of concurrent users, and the acceptable delay. There's no definitive answer. See what fits best in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Comet for the application.

Look at the example [Developing with Comet and Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using comet , just keep a jquery timer and poll your server for new updates.

Here is how you should poll.

```
0. Assume each message posted has a unique incremental rownumber.
1. pass your client page's last displayed row number.
2. check if there are any rows greater than the rownumber you passed.
3. if more,return all those rows to the client.
4. do all the above things using ajax,preferably in jquery.
```